# jquery fade content

Tags: jquery

I have navigation menu that once the user click then change and fade the content. The problem is even the child node became hidden. If I remove all the child node of my div id="witness" and id="believe" then it works fine. How to exclude child node of div id="witness" or id="believe"?

Thanks in advance.

here is my javascript

```
 $(function(){
    $("#content-linkwrap .hrefmenu").click(function(){

        $clicked = $(this);
        // if the button is not already "transformed" AND is not animated

            // each button div MUST have a "xx-button" and the target div must have an id "xx" 
            var idToLoad = $clicked.attr("id").split('-');

            //we search trough the content for the visible div and we fade it out
            $("#description").find("div:visible").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                //once the fade out is completed, we start to fade in the right div
                $(this).parent().find("#"+idToLoad[0]).fadeIn();
            })

    });
});
```

here is my html

```
 <div align="center" id="content-linkwrap"><a href="#" class="link-black hrefmenu" id="witness-href">WITNESS</a><a href="#" class="link-black hrefmenu" id="believe-href">BELIEVE</a></div>

        <div id="description">
            <div id="witness" class="desc">            
                <div class="top"><div class="bottom"><div class="left"><div class="right"><div class="bl"><div class="br"><div class="tl"><div class="tr">  
                    <div style="padding: 40px 20px;">
                        <h3 class="text-orange">WITNESS</h3>
                        <p class="aboutus wpad10" align="justify">To a company that has initiated major retail projects representing more than US $10 million in investments.
                        </p>
                        <p class="aboutus" align="justify">To a conglomerate so solid and expansive with far-reaching business interests and investments in food service, real estate, electronics, heavy equipment, jewelry trading, travel, and hardware trading that spans the Philippines, Hong Kong, Singapore and Malaysia. </p>                
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="clearleft"></div>
                </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div> 
            </div>

            <div id="believe" class="desc">                
                <div class="top"><div class="bottom"><div class="left"><div class="right"><div class="bl"><div class="br"><div class="tl"><div class="tr">  
                    <div style="padding: 40px 20px;">
                        <h3 class="text-orange">BELIEVE</h3>
                        <p class="aboutus wpad10" align="justify">In a corporation that toasts not only the successes – but  also the opportunities.
                        </p>
                        <p class="aboutus wpad10" align="justify">In a business entity that puts a high premium on freedom and creative participation of its people at all levels…</p>
                        <p class="aboutus wpad10" align="justify">In a management that is committed to corporate expansion, to the personal growth of its people, and to partnerships and ventures that are mutually beneficial…</p>             
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="clearleft"></div>
                </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
            </div>                                                    
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have the following, where the find() matches all the child 'div' elements even those nested deep underneath the 'description' element:

```
$("#description").find("div:visible").fadeOut();
```

To just match the immediate children of the 'description' element which are visible, you can use this code instead:

```
$("#description").children().filter(":visible").fadeOut();
```

For more information, see the [jQuery Traversing API documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing).

Comment: hi matt,

thank you so much. It's working perfectly.

I am too much very proud to use this forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you fade out an element, then **all** its contents are faded out, so there is no way to exclude certain child elements form the animation. My suggestion would be to use a more specific selector to pick the elements you really do want to fade out.